# Trying to Create a Binary Search Tree in C with Scanned Values

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I'm having a lot of trouble with this. I've looked at many examples and similar implementations and I still can't figure out why this isn't working. For some reason, my code is taking every new value and making it the new head, and deleting the previous tree essentially. Instead of inserting the value, it says the head is null every time and rewrites the value stored in the head...The following is my code:

```
typedef struct studentRec{
    int id;
    char name[25]; //the name has a maximum length of 25 letters
    char major[15]; //the major array has a max length of 15
    int year;
    struct studentRec *left, *right;
}student;

student* createNode(int ID, char *name, char *major, int year);
student* initBST(FILE *input, char *argv);
student* addNode(student *head, int ID, char *name, char *major, int year);
int Search(student *head);
void printInorder(student *n);


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
FILE *input;
printf("This is the name of input: %s\n", argv[1]);
student *mainHead = malloc(sizeof(student*));
mainHead = initBST(input, argv[1]);
printInorder(mainHead);
return 0;
}

student* initBST(FILE *input, char *argv){
    int ID = -1;
    input = fopen(argv, "r");
    fscanf(input, "%d", &ID);
    student *head = malloc(sizeof(student*));
    int grade = -1;
    while(ID != 0){ 
        char *first, *last, *major, *name;
        first = malloc(25*sizeof(char));
        last = malloc(25*sizeof(char));
        major = malloc(25*sizeof(char));
        name = malloc(25*sizeof(char));
        fscanf(input, "%d", &ID);
        if(ID == 0){
        break;
        }
        fscanf(input, "%s %s  %s  %d", first, last, major, &grade);
        sprintf(name, "%s %s", first, last);

        head = addNode(head, ID, name, major, grade);
    }
    return head;
}

void printInorder(student *n){
     if(n != NULL){
         printInorder(n->left);
         printf("This is the current value of ID: %d\n", n->id);
         printInorder(n->right);
     }
}

student* createNode(int ID, char *name, char *major, int year){
            printf("Adding this ID value: %d\n", ID);
            student *new = malloc(sizeof(student*));
            new->left = NULL;
            new->right = NULL;
            new->id = ID;
            strcpy(new->name, name);
            strcpy(new->major, major);
            new->year = year;
            return new;
}

student* addNode(student *head, int ID, char *name, char *major, int year){ 
    if(head == NULL){
        printf("head == NULL\n");
        return createNode(ID, name, major, year);
    }
    else{
        if(ID < head->id){
            return head->left = addNode(head->left, ID, name, major, year); 
        }
        else if(ID > head->id){
            return head->right = addNode(head->right, ID, name, major, year); 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code. Have you tried stepping through it using a debugger?

Comment: Well, I just installed Linux Mint a few days ago. I'm not sure what kind of debugger is available. I just use gedit. Are there any plugins for a debugger?

Comment: outch :-) gedit is perhaps not the best tool for writing code. For a debugger try `gdb`. Tons of tutorials out there...

Comment: This is a bad question for StackOverflow.  I understand that you are stuck ... but you need to ask a question about "how do I .." and in your instance you need to ask "how do I go about debugging a program" ... which might be answered already.

Comment: And to answer your hypothetical question: (1) gdb is a debugger, (2) you can put print statements in the code to print out values and check what you'd expect them to be .... and when you go "huh?" at a print out then you know _where_ to investigate

Comment: I've been putting print statements, I just deleted them to post the code here...I know what my program is doing, I just don't understand why it is doing it. Every time it tries to insert a new node into the tree, it assumes head is NULL and creates the new data as the new head. I stated this above.

Answer (score 1):

The first call to addNode appears to work correctly and create the head. However, when initBST calls addNode the second time, addNode recurs on one of these two lines:

```
    if(ID < head->id){
        return head->left = addNode(head->left, ID, name, major, year); 
    }
    else if(ID > head->id){
        return head->right = addNode(head->right, ID, name, major, year); 
    }
```

Since both head->left and head->right are NULL, the new iteration of addNode will print your head == NULL message, but it creates the new node correctly. The other iteration of addNode (running the above code) sets head->left or head->right correctly, but it then returns that value, which initBST sets as the new head. The relevant part of addNode should look like this:

```
head->left = addNode(head->left, ID, name, major, year);
return head;
// with the other one changed as well
```

Comment: Ahh, I see now. My recursive calls were flawed. They were just returning the new node every time. Thanks, that worked perfectly!